# C# net4 Read and import RSS

Tags: c#, rss

[C# net4] Import RSS

Hi all, hope in your help.

I need import with C# net4 in my DB MySQL all news of this type rss link: http://www.remotehost.com/news/news.rss

This is my C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.ServiceModel.Syndication;
using System.Xml;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("http://www.remotehost.com/news/news.rss");
        SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);

        foreach (var item in feed.Items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Title.Text);
            Console.WriteLine(item.PublishDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

But in debug I've this error:

```
Error HTTP 401 Unauthorized
```

Can you help me? Any suggestion?
Thank you in advance.
Cheers

Comment: It looks like you have to an authentication method to access the URL. I don't know if the XmlReader class can do that, if not you have to use a WebClient and WebRequest/WebResponse. The problem is also completely unrelated to your question and to the tags.

Comment: I am dispose to change method but which to use?